# Entity states between EJB and Jersey

Tags: jpa, ejb

I'm a novice.

Does Jersey and EJB hold the same EntityManager scope?

Should I have to pass the EntityManager to EJB for same persistence context?

The primary target usage is JTA.

```java
@Stateless
class MyEJB {

    public MyEntity find(Long id) {
        ...
    }

    @PersistenceContext;
    EntityManager entityManager;
}


class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/myentity/{id}");
    public MyEntity get(@PathParam("id") final long id) {
        final MyEntity found = myEjb.find(id);
        // is found's state detached?

        // should I have to reattach?
        found.setDate(new Date());

        return found;
    }

    @EJB
    private MyEjb myEjb;

    @PersistenceContext;
    EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Jersey and EJB hold the same EntityManager scope?
>
> Should I have to pass the EntityManager to EJB for same persistence context?

I don't think that your wording is correct, but they can share the same EntityManager instance, and you have chosen the right way (through injection). Have a look at [this chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html) of the Java EE 6 Tutorial:

> To obtain an EntityManager instance, inject the entity manager into the application component:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;
```

So, once again, your approach is correct. With regards to the questions in the code comments: the fact that `MyEntity` is attached or detached, it depends on the implementation of the find method in your `EJB`. If you do the following, it will be attached:

```
public MyEntity find(Long id) {  
    return entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, id);  
}
```

Finally, doing this way, if you have chosen `JTA` to use container managed transactions, the transactions will be automatically bounded with the natural boundaries of `MyBean`'s methods. In order to have JTA transactions, you have to use this line in `persistence.xml` file:

```
 <persistence-unit name="em" transaction-type="JTA">
```